# METEOR + Iron Scaffolding bootstrap package installation error

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm getting an error when I try to installing a package in Iron Scaffolding. The package I'm trying to install is the Twitter Bootstrap.

[image: The error I'm getting when I try to install the package "twbs:bootstrap"]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You might not have handled the error event properly in the program.

Use this in function

```
function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I am new to Meteor and iron scaffolding tool. All I did was create a new app and then tried to install the bootstrap package. I'm actually following this tutorial ->  https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/how-to-build-web-apps-ultra-fast-with-meteor-iron-scaffolding-and-automatic-form-generation-11734eda8e67

Answer (score 1):

Try using `meteor` without the scaffolding tool:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

This shouldn't impact your apps structure. Packages are handled more stealthily than they used to since 0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Iron-cli has had that breaking since Meteor 1.3

You can try my workaround:
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli/issues/240

Try one of these:
For IronRouter, Meteor 1.2 style:

`$ npm install -g iron-maka`

For FlowRouter, Meteor 1.3 style:

`$ npm install -g maka-cli`